# Is there a way to hide deprecated methods?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

In my project in VS 2017, Intellisense is filled with deprecated API that take up almost 80% of all members on certain classes.

It's a long API so I would like to browse though the API while totally ignoring and avoiding those deprecated members.

Now it seems it's not possible in 2017 aside from intellisense filtering, but is there an extension of something to do the trick?

It would also be helpful if it also filters inherited members as well.
Anything like that to enhance built-in intellisense?

Comment: Is this your own API? In that case, add `[Browsable(false)]` to the methods that have been deprecated, that will hide them for all users.

Comment: No it's proprietary and not open source. Is it possible in resharper or something? I feel this feature is legit one. @jessehouwing

Comment: Certainly does sound legit, though I haven't encountered too many libs with loads of deprecated methods. They're meant to be removed after a few releases. Not to stay forever. Consider filing a feature request on the Visual Studio user voice.

Comment: @JonneyShih, you can have a try with the Resharper: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JetBrains.ReSharper and it describes "Code formatting and cleanup features allow you to get rid of unused code and help your entire team to ensure compliance to coding standards.", if it is not meet your requirement, like jessehouwing said, please report this user voice to the VS Product Team: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide

Comment: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/14015994-deprecated-objects-members-should-display-differen

Comment: Im having the same problem in Visual Studio 2019 with some deprecated methods in the Unity APIs